# Is there a mathematics field that studies the displaying of numbers?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I've read somewhere (not sure where) - that there is a dicotomy between the numbers and the symbols used for representing them, for example: We have the idea of twoness which can be represented in decimal base as $2$ and also in binary as $10$, in this case we're talking about the same number represented in two different bases. It could also be represented in roman symbols $II$ for example.

For the decimal base, there is a *logic of succession*, which is:

$$0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$$

And then when we reach nine, we *rotate* the number in the left (which was $0$ previously):

$$\color{red}{\square} 8, \color{red}{\square} 9, \color{red}{1}0,...$$

The algorithm for roman symbols is fairly different:

$$I,II,III,IV,V,VI,VII,VIII,IX,X,...$$

It's possible to express $I$, $II$, $III$ and $V$, the four is formed with a rule of subtracting $1$ from the number in the right $\color{blue}{I}\color{red}{V}=\color{red}{5}-\color{blue}{1}=4$, It's the same for nine: $\color{blue}{I}\color{red}{X}=\color{red}{10}-\color{blue}{1}=9$.

Is there a field of study for these representations? Has anyone proposed axioms for their inner working or we've always used them intuitively? I remember of reading how these representations worked, but I never read about axiomatic basis for them nor sytems with completely different axioms.

**Note**: I have no idea on how to tag this question, if you know better tags, feel free to  edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for *numeration systems*. In the book [Automatic Sequences](http://amzn.com/0521823323) by Allouche and Shallit there is a chapter on numeration systems. From the introduction of Chapter 3:

> In this chapter, we discuss how numbers can be represented by strings over a finite 
>   alphabet. Our emphasis is on the representation of integers, although we briefly 
>   discuss representations for real numbers in Section 3.4.
>
> We start with the classical base-$k$ representation, and then discuss less familiar 
>   representations such as representation in base $-k$ , Fibonacci representation, and 
>   representation in complex bases.

I haven't had time to read this chapter yet, but it seems to contain a lot of information. 57 pages, 61 exercises and discussion of 8 open problems. This might just be the place to start if you want to know more.